# Get IHTMLElement.body.innerHTML as ansi string

Tags: delphi, unicode, character-encoding, innerhtml, twebbrowser

I have the html markup with unicode symbol:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML xmlns:o = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 9.00.8112.16441"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>&#968;</P></BODY></HTML>
```

The symbol `&#968;` I insert using IHTMLTxtRange.pasteHTML. And when I use HTMLDocument2.body.innerHTML, I want to get `<P>&#968;</P>`, but instead of the string representation of a Unicode character string function return Unicode BSTR
where `&#968;`(ψ) is a Unicode character $03C8

Comment: Could you show us the code how are you getting the `innerHTML` value ? Have you tried `innerText` instead ?

Comment: @TLama Save and display in ansi only text editor (TMemo)

Comment: I meant the line of code showing the call of `HTMLDocument2.body.innerHTML` including all parameter declarations. Or try to use `innerText` instead.

Comment: @TLama Unfortunately innerText return text without html markup tags

Comment: I see. I thought the same as @kobik, the DOM parser probably looses the original value and encode it to the proper Unicode value, so there's no way to get it back as it was. However you may check the workaround I've posted below.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is the problem that you want to receive `"&#968;"` and are receiving `0x03C8` instead, or that you want to receive `0x03C8` and are receiving `"&#968;"` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, OP wants to receive `<P>&#968;</P>` but the DOM parses the document and the `body.innerHTML` returns: `<P>ψ</P>` (WideString).

Comment: Rather than using `innerHTML`, I would query the document for one of its `IPersist...` interfaces, such as `IPersistStream`, and then read the raw HTML as-is into your destination buffer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Can you give us a code example please on how it's done?

Comment: @kobik: examples have been posted in the Embarcadero forums may times before. Search the archives. Call `QueryInterface()` on the `IHTMLDocument2` interface to get an `IPersistStream` interface, then call its `save()` method, passing it an `IStream` interface to write the HTML's raw bytes to.  You can get an `IStream` using the VCL's `TStreamAdapter` class to wrap and expose any `TStream` object, such as a `TMemoryStream`, as an `IStream` interface.

Comment: Thanks @Remy. I have used `IPersistStream` to load HTML but never thought to use `Save` as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another workaround

```
function GetInnerHTMLFromBody(const ADocument: IHTMLDOCUMENT2): AnsiString;
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  startBody: integer;
  stopBody: integer;
const
  bodyTag = '<BODY>';
  closedBodyTag = '</BODY>';
begin
  Result := '';
  if ADocument <> nil then
  begin
    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Succeeded((ADocument as IPersistStreamInit).Save(
        TStreamAdapter.Create(ms, soReference) as IStream, true));
      ms.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      SetLength(Result, ms.size);
      ms.ReadBuffer(Result[1], ms.size);
      // better to use regexpr
      startBody := AnsiPos(bodyTag, Result) + Length(bodyTag);
      stopBody := AnsiPos(closedBodyTag, Result);
      Result := Copy(Result, startBody, stopBody - startBody);
    finally
      ms.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

However, this method only works with ANSI encoding html document. If the Unicode encoding you need to do an additional conversion from Unicode to AnsiString:

```
if SameText(Utf8ToAnsi(UTF8Encode(HTMLDocument2.charset)),'unicode') then
...
```

Comment: strange, all I see in the stream result is "<HTML></HTML>". I have used @TLama's code right until 'ShowMessage'...

Comment: @kobik: of course you have to navigate the browser to a URL and wait for it to load the HTML before you can then retreive its content.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, but why doesn't it works when using `PasteHTML(HTMLDoc);` as shown by the example of TLama? the document DOM returns valid `innerHTML`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, when using `IHTMLTxtRange.pasteHTML` like the OP initially asked, The result of `ISream` returns only "<HTML></HTML>" (30 bytes). I'll make some more tests...